# Regular conditional probability and absolute continuity

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let's say I have two measure spaces $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{G},\nu)$. I can consider the measure $\mu\times\nu$ over the product measurable space $(X\times Y, \mathcal{F} \times \mathcal{G})$. Let us also say that there is a coupling $\pi$ of $\mu,\nu$ such that $\pi \ll \mu\times\nu$. I.e., another probability measure over the same measurable space and such that $\pi(X\times A) = \nu(A), \pi(B\times Y) = \mu(B$).
From my understanding, if the spaces are Radon, I can define a regular conditional probability and disintegrate $\pi$ using $\mu$ and this conditional measure.
I am trying to show that $\mu\times\nu \ll \pi$. Indeed, let us call $\omega$ this conditional measure. I have that for a given measurable set $E$, $$(\mu \times \nu)(E) = \int_Y \mu(E_y) d\nu(y) = \int_X \nu(E_x)d\mu(x),$$ where $E_y = \{ x \in X : (x,y)\in E\}$ and $E_x$ is similarly defined.
Similarly, for $\pi$,
$$ \pi(E) = \int_Y \mu(E_y) dw(y|E_y).$$
If $\mu(E_y)=0$ for every $y$ then we clearly satisfy the absolute continuity constraint. Assume then that there exists a $y$ s.t. $\mu(E_y)\neq  0$  and that $\pi(E)=0.$ Using the disintegration in the other direction we also have that $$\pi(E) = \int_X \nu(E_x)d\xi(x|E_x).$$
Similar reasoning for $\nu(E_x)$.
If $\pi(E)=0$ then, denoting with $\hat{y}$ the element such that $\mu(E_\hat{y})\neq 0$  we must have that $\omega(\{\hat{y}\}|E_\hat{y})=0$. Is it possible that $\nu(\{\hat{y}\})\neq 0 $?

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I've misunderstood, but it seems to me like you're trying to prove that $\mu \times \nu \ll \pi$ for any coupling $\pi$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$.  But this is definitely false in general.  For example, let $\mu$ and $\nu$ both be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, and $\pi$ be (normalized) Lebesgue measure on the diagonal $\{ (x,x) : 0 \leq x \leq 1 \}$.  Then it's clear that $\mu \times \nu$, which is $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, is not absolutely continuous with respect to $\pi$.

Comment: Sorry, I actually wanted to exclude these cases with $\pi \ll \mu\times \nu$, are these the only cases where absolute continuity fails to hold? Is $\pi \ll \mu\times\nu$ sufficient?

Comment: @ProbabilityNewbie $\pi \not\ll \mu \times\nu$ in this case.  But there are also examples where $\pi \ll \mu \times \nu$ and $\mu \times \nu \not\ll \pi$.  For example, let $\pi$ be normalized $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on the strip $\{ (x,y) : ||x-y|| \leq 1/4 \}$ (where $|| x-y ||$ is the distance between $x$ and $y$ on the torus).

Comment: Thanks a lot, just what I was looking for. Now trying to understand it more deeply. You are considering a 2-Torus and then a strip of the torus? How do you define a distance on the torus?

Comment: $||u||$ is the distance from $u$ to the nearest integer

Comment: And I think that the product of the marginals is the Lebesgue measure over the corresponding projections, right? What is the set where they disagree?